# What is wrong with my UIView Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

i am trying to create animation with 3 steps. First step should go to right direction little bit on zoomed pic. Second step is just zoom in effect to other picture in 3 seconds. Last step is zoom out with different pic in 3 seconds again. I did first two steps exactly as i want but when i add 3. step somethings went wrong. Its like its trying to do 2. and 3. steps together.  Please help me. Here is my code.

```
imgAnimationBase.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation-1.jpg"];

imgAnimationBase.alpha = 1.0;
imgAnimationBase.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
imgAnimationBase.frame=CGRectMake(20, imgAnimationBase.frame.origin.y, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.width, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.height);

[UIView transitionWithView:imgAnimationBase
   duration:3.0f
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
 animations:^{
     imgAnimationBase.frame=CGRectMake(-110, imgAnimationBase.frame.origin.y, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.width, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.height);
 }
           completion:^(BOOL finished) {

               imgAnimationBase.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
               imgAnimationBase.frame=CGRectMake(10, imgAnimationBase.frame.origin.y, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.width, imgAnimationBase.frame.size.height);
               [UIView transitionWithView:imgAnimationBase
                                 duration:3.0f
                                  options:NO
                               animations:^{
                                   imgAnimationBase.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation-2.jpg"];
                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                                           imgAnimationBase.alpha = 1.0;
                                           imgAnimationBase.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);

                                   }];

                               }
                                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {



                                             [UIView transitionWithView:imgAnimationBase
                                                               duration:3.0f
                                                                options:NO
                                                             animations:^{
                                                                 imgAnimationBase.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"animation-3.jpg"];
                                                                 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{

                                                                     imgAnimationBase.alpha = 1.0;
                                                                     imgAnimationBase.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
                                                                 }];

                                                             }
                                                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                                             }];
                                         }];
               }];
```

Comment: Why are you calling `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` inside animations block?

Comment: Ah yes thank you @Losiowaty,  i insert it by mistake. It solved the problem. Cannot believe did such mistake.  Write it down as an answer and i ll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - there is no need to call `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` second time when you are already in the `animations` block.